# How to capture curl trace output into a log file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, curl

I have the below shell script which execute a curl command with trace. I am able to capture the output(api response) of curl command into the log file, but unable to capture the trace logs into the log file. Please help.

```
#! /bin/bash

app_header="app_header:test_app"
cmd="curl -ivk —trace GET https://app.corp.com/api/state/1231231?id=21"
echo $cmd >> /log/call_app_service.log

for i in {1..2}
do
    echo "Running $i times" >> /log/call_app_service.log
    $cmd -H $app_header >> /log/call_app_service.log
    echo "\n" >> /log/call_app_service.log
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Replace this ```$cmd -H $app_header >> /log/call_app_service.log```  with this ```$cmd -H $app_header 2>> /log/trace_output.log >> /log/call_app_service.log```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am able to capture the output(api response) of curl command into the log file, but unable to capture the trace logs into the log file.

The output you're capturing is from `stdout`.  The output you're missing is from `stderr` which is still going to the terminal instead of the file.

You can redirect standard error (fd 2) to standard output (fd 1)

```
$cmd -H $app_header >> /log/call_app_service.log 2>&1
```